# Browsers redirect from local "index.html"-file to "file:///"-root

Tags: ubuntu, wget, firefox, browser, kubuntu

I downloaded the website https://www.untools.co/ with

```
wget --mirror --convert-links https://www.untools.co/
```

and have respective pages on my filesystem:

[image]

When I open `untools.co/index.html` with Firefox I can see the page for half a second, then I am re-directed to `file:///`.

I do not believe this is an issue with the html file, because when I open them in virtual machine's Windows with Firefox, I don't have any issues.

This is the case not only with Firefox but also with the browswers Chrome, Brave, Konqueror, so I guess it must be something with my Kubuntu 20.04.

Or it could be that there is some other weird redirect going on, I am not aware of. For example at https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file- I read about how to redirect from index.html - however, I want to make sure, I do not get redirected.

Comment: There may be some javascript that is forcing a redirect to `/`, which makes sense for a web site but not so much for a filesystem. Consider starting a local webserver to serve the content instead of reading it from the filesystem, or disable javascript when viewing it.

Comment: @larsks: I disabled JavaScript and indeed, I was able to display the page. Is it possible to override that redirect, by adjusting the downloaded files? Or can I add some code into the folder that turns off JavaScript if I open the files?

Comment: If you don't know how that is possible, do you know how to follow your suggestion of starting a local webserver? I tried to follow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/set_up_a_local_testing_server and was able to open the file `index.html`, after using the command `python3 -m http.server` in the folder in which `index.html` is in. But, when I clicked on a link (that should open the html file `minto-pyramid`), I got a dialog to save the respective file to hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem, as we covered in the comments, is that the main `index.html` contains some embedded Javascript that forces a redirect to `/`. This makes sense for a website, where something like `http://example.com/foo/` will redirect to `http://example.com/`, but it's less useful when accessing things via the filesystem, where it ends up redirecting you to the filesystem root.

The simplest solution is probably to run a local webserver. As you've suggested, `python3 -m http.server` is generally a good choice, and that successfully serves `index.html`.

When you click on the "Minto pyramid" link, you'll see that links to `/minto-pyramid`. The problem you have now is that `minto-pyramid` is a file without an extension, so there's no way for Python's http server to know what MIME type to use. It gets delivered to your browser as a `application/octet-stream` document, so your browser assumes it's not something it can display and prompts you to save it to a file.

The quickest solution is to set up a webserver that will default to type `text/html` for files without a recognized extension. You can do this straight from the command line using [darkhttpd](https://github.com/emikulic/darkhttpd), which may be packaged for your distribution, like this:

```
darkhttpd . --port 8000 --default-mimetype text/html
```

But you can do the same thing with Python if you drop this into `server.py` in the same directory as `index.html`:

```
import http.server
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import socketserver

Handler = http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

Handler.extensions_map = {
    ".html": "text/html",
    ".png": "image/png",
    ".jpg": "image/jpg",
    ".svg": "image/svg+xml",
    ".css": "text/css",
    ".js": "application/javascript",
    "": "text/html",  # Default
}

httpd = socketserver.TCPServer(("", 8000), Handler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And then run it:

```
python3 server.py
```

Both of these solutions will let you follow the `minto-pyramid` link and have it display in your browser.

Comment: I went with your python approach. Turns out there are some php files in another website... how do I extend your server.py script? I already searched in the internet, but did not manage to do it properly. E.g. I added `".php": "application/javascript",` based on https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-put-PHP-codes-in-js-extension-files, but that did not work.

Comment: PHP files need to be processed by PHP, *on the server*. You're not going to be able to serve those out with a simple solution like this. At this point, you might as well install a reall webserver like nginx or Apache along with php support.